# python selnium website login except question

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, selenium-webdriver, try-catch

The error message is not print
What's the problem? ㅠㅠㅠㅠ

```
 uid = id
 upw = pw

try:  
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="userID"]').send_keys(uid)  
            action.reset_actions()
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="userPWD"]').send_keys(upw) 
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btnLogin"]').click() 
        except Exception as e: 
                print("{} 계정 로그인이 실패하였습니다.".format(uid))
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to print the exception, you need to actually print e, not uid:

```
.....
except Exception as e: 
    print("{} 계정 로그인이 실패하였습니다.".format(uid))
    print(e)
```